# Krull's theorem and uniqueness

Tags: commutative-algebra

Commutative rings with unit must have a maximal ideal by Krull's theorem.

But is it true, in general, that such sets must have a unique maximal ideal?

Does it matter if the ring is finite or infinite?

Comment: Is it called Krull's theorem? And for your other two questions: Consider the integers, and Z/6.

Comment: Answered my own question.....
If we have $C([0,1])$ then there are an infinite number of maximal ideals; for any $x \in [0,1]$ define $M_x = \{f|f(x)=0\}$ and this can be shown to be a maximal ideal.

Comment: Commutative unital rings with a unique maximal ideal form a special class of rings, called "local rings". It is possible to have commutative rings with one, or any finite number, or an infinite number of maximal ideals.

Comment: @DylanWilson: I think what the OP is calling Krull's theorem is the statement that any ideal maximal with respect to not intersecting with a multiplicative subset of a ring is prime. I also believe Matsumara uses this terminology, though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The "result due to Krull" about rings with identity always having maximal ideals is true (with the same proof) even for noncommutative rings, and moreover, the same sort of proof shows rings have maximal right ideals and maximal left ideals.

Andrew mentioned in the comments that commutative rings with identity having a unique maximal ideal are called local rings, and these are indeed a very important class of rings. However, certainly not all rings are local. $\mathbb{Z}$ has multiple maximal ideals, one corresponding to each prime element of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Actually in noncommutative ring theory, we also talk about local rings. The defintion is a little different though: "has a unique maximal right ideal." This turns out to be equivalent to "has a unique maximal left ideal," and it implies that the ring has a unique maximal ideal. *However* there are noncommutative rings with unique maximal two-sided ideals which do not have unique maximal right ideals. An example would be an $2\times 2$ matrix ring over a field, which has maximal ideal $\{0\}$, but which has more than two maximal right ideals.